# Retrieve number via JSON and store in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, c, json, variables

Alright so I am very new to programming and have only learned a little bit of basic C.

```
https://api.vircurex.com/api/get_info_for_1_currency.json?base=DOGE&alt=BTC

http://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/how-to-access-JSON-data-in-HTML5-apps

http://jsbin.com/IQUjUkiX/1/edit
```

Basically what I want to do is retrieve the json from "http://pastebin.com/4SPcTFbQ"**(Link 1)** and store on of the numbers it returns in some sort of variable. *(kind of like using scanf() to retrieve the number and store it to a variable)*

From what I have been researching it cannot be done through C and I believe has to be done through javascript. On this site **(refer to pastebin Link 2)** they provide this example, **(refer to pastebin Link 3)** but when I try to swap out their example json for the vircurex one it does not seem to work anymore.

Any help at all would be very much appreciated!

Here is the example:

HTML

```
<h3>Get JSON with padding</h3>

<button onclick="doJSON1()">Get JSON</button>
<br>
<br>
<hr>

<h3>Get JSON with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header: *</h3>

<button onclick="doJSON2()">Get JSON</button>
<br>
<br>
<hr>

<h3>Get JSON with NO Access-Control-Allow-Origin header</h3>

<button onclick="doJSON3()">Get JSON</button>
```

Javascript

```
function doJSON1() {
    $.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com/?alloworigin=false&callback=?', function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    });
}

function doJSON2() {
    $.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com/?alloworigin=true', function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    });
}

function doJSON3() {
    $.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com/?alloworigin=false', function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    });
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/gnwgL/)

Comment: You mention C in your question, but tagged it as C# - this changes the answer dramatically. Which are you using?

Comment: See [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) Of course providing your code would help a great deal, prefereably with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Sorry I meant to just put C

Comment: Consider using [`Unobtrusive JavaScript`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and as you are using jQuery then I would suggest using [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: The answer depends on _how_ and _what_ you want to do with the variable. Are you working on some kind of website (I ask because I'm not sure how you would need C then)? In that case you basically have everything you need at hand: `data` contains every variable declared in the json. Access it using `data.yourvariablename`. I think you will get problems with the same origin policy, however.

Comment: The first server has cross-origin policies set to allow JSONP for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Example, see Javascript's [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) for declaring variables.

HTML

```
<h3>Get JSON with padding</h3>

<button id="ex1">Get JSON</button>
<br>
<br>
<hr>

<h3>Get JSON with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header: *</h3>

<button id="ex2">Get JSON</button>
<br>
<br>
<hr>

<h3>Get JSON with NO Access-Control-Allow-Origin header</h3>

<button id="ex3">Get JSON</button>
```

Javascript

```
var data1,
    data2,
    data3;

function doJSON1() {
    $.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com/?alloworigin=false&callback=?', function (data) {
        data1 = data;
        console.log(data1);
    });
}

function doJSON2() {
    $.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com/?alloworigin=true', function (data) {
        data2 = data;
        console.log(data3);
    });
}

function doJSON3() {
    $.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com/?alloworigin=false', function (data) {
        data3 = data;
        console.log(data3);
    });
}

$('#ex1').on('click', doJSON1);
$('#ex2').on('click', doJSON2);
$('#ex3').on('click', doJSON3);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/h6BbP/)